# Getter for 'value' overrides Objective-C method 'value' from superclass 'NSObject'

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have a managed Swift class defined like this (removed irrelevant stuff):

```
@objc public class WordMapping: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var value: String
    @NSManaged var key: String

    ...
}
```

This compiled and work nicely so far. With XCode 6.3 however I get errors that setters or getters from superclasses would be overridden, e.g. for value the message is as written in the title. However, there is no value member in NSObject at all. So, what's the right correction for my code here?

Comment: I have copied your code into an Xcode 6.3 beta 2 app and it compiles without errors or warnings. There must be something else ...

Comment: I have Version 6.3 (6D532l). The about box doesn't tell me which beta it is.

Comment: Yes, that's the same one.

Comment: How can it behave differently then? I installed 6.3 in this very week, so I should be on the latest one.

Comment: I have no idea. The Xcode 6.3 beta 2 release notes state *"Swift now detects discrepancies between overloading and overriding in the Swift type system and the effective behavior seen via the Objective-C runtime."* but I don't yet see how that applies here. – What happens if you just copy the class definition into a new project?